# Have the central div define the width of the others

Tags: html, css

i'm working on a sort of LED-Banner-Simulation with text running from right to left in one line.

I always show 3 words: the last, the current, the next word. They get updated via a js timer so that the current becomes the last, the next the current etc...

The user shall always focus on the central word, thus i want to have it centered within the container.

`|last_current_next|`

its fixed widht for the outer container so the outer words may be cut off when they are very long, which is ok.They should be cut off like this:

`la |st_current_ne| xt`
but i only get this working: `|la_curr_next|`

I've been working with floats but they give me a result where the outer words stick to the border of the box, like:

`|last<_____current______>next|`

I need them to stick to the central word, like:

`|____>last_current_next<_____|`

that's my css. any ideas?

```
#outputfield{
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
white-space:nowrap;

}

#pastContainer, #futureContainer, #presentContainer{
font-size: 4.5em;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
}

#pastContainer, #futureContainer{
background: red;
 }

 #pastContainer {
width: auto;
text-align: right;
overflow: hidden;
color:#CECECE;  
 }

 #presentContainer{
width: auto;
display:inline;
zoom: 1;
display: table;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
background:yellow;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px #FFF;

 }

#futureContainer {
width: auto;
text-align: left;
overflow: hidden;
color: #CECECE;
}`
```

Comment: Could you please share the html (a jsfiddle would be great)? It's a little hard without the js to see exactly what is happening but from what I see, the problem is that your past and future container have their `text-align` defined as `left` and `right` which automatically will push them on the side. The trick here is that you may not know the size of the present container, and thus without js it is hard to guess at which distance from the center you'd like to display those 2 containers. Would a js solution be viable for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment, I guessed the html you had and created a very basic "led-banner".
Actually, you don't need the `text-align` for the future and past container. And you should remove the `display:table` (if that is possible, hard to know without seeing your js).
Then, simply add a `display:inline-block;` for your 3 elements and you should be ok.
see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfE8N/1/).

```
#outputfield{
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
white-space:nowrap;
background-color:gray;
}

#pastContainer, #futureContainer, #presentContainer{
font-size: 1.5em;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
white-space:nowrap;
width: auto;
display:inline-block; <-- add this line
overflow: hidden;
}

#pastContainer, #futureContainer{
background: red;
 }

 #pastContainer {
color:#CECECE;  
 }

 #presentContainer{
display:inline;
text-align:center;
background:yellow;
text-shadow: -1px -1px 0px #FFF;
zoom: 1;
 }

#futureContainer {
color: #CECECE;
}`
```

---

**EDIT**: with javascript

the absolute position is the trick here. So remove the `inline-block` I hinted before hand, add a `position:relative` to the parent, and update your javascript

```
var i = 1;
var wordsArray = ("xxx Here comes a very long text with short an ververyveryverylong words xxx").split(" ");

changeWords();
window.setInterval(changeWords,1000);

function changeWords(){
    $('#pastContainer').html(wordsArray[i-1]);
    $('#presentContainer').html(wordsArray[i]);
    $('#futureContainer').html(wordsArray[i+1]);      
    i++;
    if(i >= wordsArray.length){i=1;}

    var centerPoint = $('#outputfield').width()/2;
    var myPastWidth = $('#pastContainer').width();
    var myPresentWidth2 = $('#presentContainer').width()/2;
    var elementDephase = myPastWidth + myPresentWidth2 - centerPoint;
    $('#pastContainer').css({left: - elementDephase});
    $('#presentContainer').css({left: (- myPresentWidth2 + centerPoint)});
    $('#futureContainer').css({left: (+ myPresentWidth2 + centerPoint)});  
}
```

So first of all I updated your javascript to have a nicer call (using setInterval instead of calling the function from inside the function).

Then the idea is simply to check the size of the middle word, to center it and push both other words on the left respectively on the right. If you want to add a small gap between words, just play with the distances I put on the `left` argument.
See the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfE8N/12/).

Comment: Hi leMoisela,thanks for your comments. I updated your fiddle ( you have to click 10 alert boxes away first). As you see the central word is not always centered. recalculation with js would be ok....
http://jsfiddle.net/mfE8N/6/

Comment: that's pure magic! great. I'm struggling with adding a padding to the center div so that the words don't clamp on each other. solved it with manually adding a &nsp; but using a padding/margin thing would be nicer

Comment: check how I added the padding variable in the js http://jsfiddle.net/mfE8N/13/. Now you just change this number to regulate it